# Error in Java, but not showing where, what can I do?

Tags: java, error-handling

Sometimes, when my Java app runs in Netbeans7.4 it generates some error messages like the following :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 7
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTextViewForTab(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1706)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.calculateTabHeight(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1717)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.calculateMaxTabHeight(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1742)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI.calculateMaxTabHeight(MetalTabbedPaneUI.java:1147)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.calculateTabRects(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2586)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.calculateLayoutInfo(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2512)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.layoutContainer(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2407)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1503)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1492)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1688)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1623)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:691)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:688)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1676)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 7
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTextViewForTab(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1706)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.calculateTabHeight(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1717)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.calculateMaxTabHeight(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1742)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI.calculateMaxTabHeight(MetalTabbedPaneUI.java:1147)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.calculateTabRects(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2586)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.calculateLayoutInfo(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2512)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.layoutContainer(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2407)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1503)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1492)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1688)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1623)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:691)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:688)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1676)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

But it doesn't show which line in my code caused the error, the app seems to execute fine, what can I do ? This only happens sometime, if I run it again, it may or may not have the same error.

Comment: It's always errors but you should not care about it, you can put try/catch block on it.

Comment: Well it's happening in a vector/array sized 7, can you narrow it down and locate it within your code?

Comment: Isn't that just a bug in netbeans ui?

Comment: What's happening is that you're giving something in the AWT bad data, and later, when it acts on that bad data, the error occurs. It would appear to be related to a tabbed pane, so you need to review all your code that deals with those and see if you can find the problem.  Isn't programming fun?

Comment: As a hint, it's a Vector that has only 7 entries, and you're trying to access the 8th entry.

Comment: There's a possibility that there's a concurrent modification issue wherein the UI gets passed a `Vector` of a certain size, elements are removed, and the UI doesn't get informed that the size is reduced.

Comment: (This isn't a problem that anyone else can solve for you, unless they've recently had the exact same problem, so you need to work it out yourself.)

Comment: @turbo The source info is available from the backtrace.  The vector is one named `htmlViews` defined inside `BasicTabbedPaneUI`, so it's not in his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close to that line of code in the BasicTabbedPaneUI source, the only thing getTextViewForTab() does that is a possible match is getting the element from something called HtmlViews at the value of a variable called tabIndex.  Does your code remove tabs from the tab view at some point?  If so, my guess would be that it does so in a way that does not update the UI that one of the tabs is now gone, and that's what causes this error.

Comment: The index is probably `tabPane.getTabCount() - 1`; `tabPane` is a `JTabbedPane` field inside `BasicTabbedPaneUI`, and `htmlViews` is a separate field, so it looks like `BasicTabbedPaneUI` is supposed to be keeping the length of `htmlViews` in sync with `tabPane`.  So it sounds like something close to what you said, unless it's a concurrency problem or a bug in Swing.

Comment: My code does remove tabs from the tab view, but how to update the UI ? Do a repaint() or revalidate () ?

Comment: There are two things to check: (1) changes to the UI should be done in the event dispatch thread, so make sure that anything like that you do is in SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() or .invokeLater(), (2) JTabbedPane.ModelListener.stateChanged() is used when the model changes and the UI needs to be informed.  I actually suspect the latter in your case; if you're removing the tab in the model for the UI and not notifying it, it seems to me you would run into this bug, at least occasionally...